# Redirecionar se o cesto estiver vazio | Woocommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin, woocommerce, plugin-wordpress

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirecionar' );
function redirecionar(){
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( is_page('carrinho-de-compras') and !sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
```

OU

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirecionar' );
function redirecionar(){
    global $woocommerce;
    if( is_cart() && WC()->cart->cart_contents_count < 1 ){
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
    }
}
```

Pretendo redirecionar para a página principal se o carrinho estiver vazio!
O redirecionamento só é possível se atualizar a página ( F5 ).

Desde já obrigado!

Comment: Seguindo sua linha de raciocínio o caminho que eu vejo aí seria javascript amigo, tenta aproveitar a biblioteca jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Todo (ou quase todo) carrinho vazio no wordpress tem a tag p com a class cart_empty, então, com um simples Javascript você pode verificar o length e se for maior do que 0, é porque o carrinho está vazio, e então, redireciona.

```
const redirectIfEmpty = () => {
    const lengthCartEmpty = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-empty').length;
    if(lengthCartEmpty > 0){
        window.location.href = 'www.seusite.com.br';
    }
}

redirectIfEmpty();
```

Comment: Não funciona, mas obrigado na mesma!

Comment: Funciona. Depende de como você aplicou.

Comment: Eu apliquei bem, não funciona. Obrigado na mesma Carvalho!